# jQuery addClass does not apply style dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, code-injection, addclass

I'm trying to apply a style dynamically to a few dropdown lists in my page. Using jQuery addClass does indeed add the class to all 'Select' elements, as i can see this from my Chrome console. However the styles are not applied to the elements.

Now if i manually add the class to each select element individually, and then save the page and refresh it, the style is applied to the element.

Any idea why the styling is not applied with jquery class injection?

```
$("select").addClass("select js-select");
```

Comment: Can you post an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Could you post a sample of the HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please post a Fiddle. Help us in helping you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that the styles are not applied, but are the classes "select js-select" added to the select inputs? Then there must be some problem with the css or maybe the browser.

$("select").addClass(..) should work, it isn't required that you specify by ID or class.

Comment: You're right, once I realized he was actually targeting the select element.

Comment: This is now resolved. Here is the fiddle with the injection working correctly. The problem was with the css and javascript includes. They were not working correctly when adding them as resources in the fiddle, however when adding them as links instead, it works fine. Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5qKV2/)

Answer (score 2):

This example works:

```
<p><a href="#" id="clicker">Add Class</a></p>
<div id="select">Hello World</div>
```

javascript

```
$("#clicker").click(function () {

    $("#select").addClass("select js-select");
});
```

From looking at your code, it seems that the $("select") should have either an ID or class selector on it. By having one of those selectors, your code will know the target to apply the styles to. Otherwise your code works fine.

Good luck, and hope this helps.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle, hope you guys can help me out: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gc3wQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if you change the onDomReady to onLoad.
As in http://jsfiddle.net/gc3wQ/9/

Comment: Still not working. The styles applied are pretty substantial, and they would be very noticeable. I see that using 'onLoad' is injecting the classes, however the styles are not applied. Yet if you manually put the classes in the select elements, the styles are applied.

Comment: Now it works, but only not in jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gc3wQ/11/

Take on the habit to wrap all your jQuery code in side of a:
$(document).ready(function(){

});
See also: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29

Comment: Are you seeing the styles applied in the fiddle? I am still not seeing them. Please add the styles manually first, to get an idea of the styles i am trying to inject. I am injecting these styles into a dynamic form on my page, so theoretically if i can inject the styles into select elements i create on the dom, i should be able to also inject the styles onto dynamically created elements.

Comment: The style is changed in jsFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gc3wQ/12/).
Try with $(document).ready(function(){ //code });  if it does not work in your real code.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding to LazyTarget's answer.**

The styles you are trying to add with a class are overridden by CSS that may be already present in the element.

for example, this won't work (will not hide the div)

```js
$(function (argument) {

  function loaded(){
    $('.landing .scroll').addClass('hidden');
  }

  loaded();

})
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.shown{
  display: block;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="shown">
 <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```